# inaccurate java.pow() results

Tags: java, math, floating-point

I am trying to take two numbers and get the square of them.  Using several numbers some work, but this one is giving me problems pow(.0305,2).  Using a calculator i get an answer of: 0.093025; but when I use java i get an answer of:9.609999999999999E-4.  I need .0305 because I am taking 3.05/100 which is .0305.

I have found through trial that if I do .pow(.305,2), that does give me my need answer, but then I would have to get that with 3.05/100.

EDIT:(adding code)

```
double weight=3.05;
double TapeLength=100.00;
double ftwt= weight/TapeLength; this gives me: 0.093025
double ftwt= Math.pow(ftwt,2); //this gives me: 9.3025E-4
```

everything is cast as a double.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Please show some example code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: .0305 to the power of 2 is not 0.093025, so I don't believe that you got that result on your calculator.

Comment: See also the info page on the [floating-point](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info) tag.

Comment: .0305 to the power of 2 == 0.00093025

Comment: (3.05 / 100) ^ 2 = 9.3025 / 10000 = 0.00093025

Comment: In Scala, which uses the JVM, I get `math.pow(.0305f, 2)` as result `res53: Double = 9.302500209063293E-4` which is not 9.6e-4, while using floats explicitly.

Comment: The code you've added to your question gives the expected result (9.3025e-4), so I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: I have to agree with @Oli. Other than your incorrect "this gives me: 0.093025" (it should be 0.0305), what you're getting is the _correct_ value. What's the problem?

Comment: the problem, I am having is that when using calculators such as built into windows and Google, i am getting a different answer then what Java is giving me.  the answer that I get from both windows and Google give me an answer of: 0.00093025.  That is the answer I need to get.  Looking through some of the articles posted, would using Big Decimal help?

Comment: Paul, 9.3025E-4 _is_ 0.00093025, just expressed in exponential form.

Comment: I would like to thank James Montagne for his article.  After doing the calculations I need to format it for string output.  I am sorry for the confusion, because I realize I did not mention that that was what I was planning with it.  So basically I took it and then used in it in:

    System.out.printf("%.8f",ftwt);

that gives me the exact answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're *really* getting `9.609999999999999E-4` as the result, you're doing something wrong other than what you have in you question. The following code (in Eclipse 3.7.1):

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double dd = .0305;
        System.out.println (Math.pow(dd, 2));
        System.out.println ("%.8f\n", Math.pow(dd, 2));
    }
}
```

produces:

```
9.3025E-4
0.00093025
```

which are *both* correct <sup>(a)</sup>, just expressed in different output formats. The default for `double` is exponential format in this case but the last line shows how you can get different formats.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Just on the off chance that you're confused by the exponential form (based on your comments), `0.00093025` *is* the same as `9.3025E-4` since the latter means`9.3025 x 10-4` (`9.3025` with the decimal point shifted four positions to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problems with order of magnitude, which I think are just a typing mistakes, if your concern is that you get 0.00096xxxxx you should specify them as double from start. You are making them float which means you lose precision and only then they are cast to double. Then the error is compounded by squaring them.

Making them doubles will probably help, but you have to remember that when you are dealing with binary representation of decimal rationals there may not be an exact representation with a finite number of digits.

Comment: Doing this calculation in float should not give you 9.6xxx.

Comment: I was lazy to type the mantissa. Fixed. I am just trusting the original poster that he is getting a wrong significant digits for the exponential

Comment: It shouldn't give you 0.00096xxx either.  It should give you 0.00093025.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Math.pow(x, 2)` is much, much slower than using `x * x`  That is because it is the same was `Math.exp(Math.log(x) * n)`  As it does much more calculations it tends to have a larger rounding error. (So its a bad idea all round IMHO)